# Caching group membership with from Azure AD with Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm using the [Graph API Client library](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient) in my Web API project to check if the user belongs to a Group for security reasons. I realized that it is too slow, it takes almost 2 seconds to query the Azure AD. Is there a way to cache this information? Or does someone have any advice on how to handle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to cache this you should leverage the new group claims feature in Azure AD. This will deliver group membership claims to your Web API application as claims in the JWT token for your authenticated user.

Here is a link from the Azure AD blog describing the feature.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2014/12/18/azure-active-directory-now-with-group-claims-and-application-roles.aspx

Here is a link to blog I recently wrote on this subject that shows how to do this from your Web API.

http://justazure.com/azure-active-directory-part-4-group-claims/

Comment: THANKS A LOT!Could you please confirm that there is no other documentation besides samples and source code for everything related to the new versions of  Azure AD apis . For example : the application manifest.

Comment: Hi Rodrigo - we have Graph API documented here https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/hh974476.aspx and this on API versions and features: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn835125.aspx.  You'll see on the app object the property groupMembershipClaims.  We plan to have a document about the application manifest.  Through the azure management portal, download/upload manifest is essentially a GET and a PATCH on the application entity in AAD Graph.

Comment: I should note that users in large organisations may belong to many groups. I've encountered the situation where the JWT was too large to fit in the header and my request failed. So I'm doing manual lookups thru MS Graph API.