# How to troubleshoot App slowness with Azure AD calls?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I've inherited an ASP.NET MVC app that takes between twenty seconds and a minute to display every single page. The vast majority of that time is spent in `ActiveDirectoryClient`. It looks like the original author may have read [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900948/how-to-check-if-a-user-that-is-in-azure-active-directory-belongs-to-a-specific-g) about how to check group membership.

Calling `ActiveDirectoryClient.Users.Where(...).ExecuteAsync()` takes 3-10 seconds on a good day. Calling `IUserFetcher.MemberOf.ExecuteAsync()` takes another 5-7 seconds. Basically, every use of `ActiveDirectoryClient` takes several seconds, and there are many of them.

I tried using `ActiveDirectoryClient.IsMemberOfAsync(...)`, but this just consumes 1.5 GB of RAM and never returns. (By "never" I mean I waited five minutes before stopping the debugger.)

I suspect that the problem is not with these bits of code, but some overall misconfiguration of Azure or the graph client. So maybe this question isn't even on the right site. Where do I begin troubleshooting this?

Comment: Checking group memberships on every request sounds like a bad idea. You'll hit the Graph APIs rate limits pretty quickly.

Comment: @juunas What's the alternative? Something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29704609/8773089)?

Comment: Well, that's one solution, but comes with drawbacks. There is a limit of 200 ids that can be in the token. If a user has more, there will be none in the token. I have a couple opinions on this here: https://joonasw.net/view/using-groups-vs-using-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps. If you wanna go with groups, I'd check memberships on login and store them in their session.

Comment: You already have some good suggestions from @juunas .. I would add that looking at the code it seems you're using older `Azure AD Graph API` and it's client libraries. Unless there is a good reason/limitation you're running into.. consider using newer `Microsoft Graph API`. You can read about comparison and recommendation here.. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/

Comment: @RohitSaigal AFAIK, the only reason is that it was written around Q2 2018.